# swap using swapExactTokensForTokens but execution reverted

Tags: solidity, pancakeswap

I'm trying to swap BUSD to USDT using pancake swap on the testnet but whenever I try to swap using swapExactTokensForTokens function, I get "execution reverted" error, can you help me find the problem?

```
contract swaptest{
    address router = 0x9Ac64Cc6e4415144C455BD8E4837Fea55603e5c3;
    address busd = 0x78867BbEeF44f2326bF8DDd1941a4439382EF2A7;
    address usdt = 0x7ef95a0FEE0Dd31b22626fA2e10Ee6A223F8a684;
    address wbnb = 0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd;
    function approve() public {
        IBEP20(0x78867BbEeF44f2326bF8DDd1941a4439382EF2A7).approve(router , 1 ether);
    }
    function swap() public {
        address[] memory path;
        path[0] = busd;
        path[1] = wbnb;
        path[2] = usdt;
        IPancakeRouter02(router).swapExactTokensForTokens( 1 ether , 0 , path , address(this) , block.timestamp );
    }
}
```

first I send 2 BUSD to the contract and then I execute approve function and then swap function that is not working.
I'm using this website for addresses: https://bsc.kiemtienonline360.com/
.here is the message from remix:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
"code": 3,
"message": "execution reverted",
"data": "0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032"
}
```

and here is transaction hash:
0x180d8f44b3be3e0c06986f69acb2f343f71a9598dad1865caff73c50946c09f3

Answer (score 0):

<del>Mainnet Pancakeswap router on bsc: 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E</del>

<del>busd: 0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56</del>

<del>wbnb: 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c</del>

<del>usdt: 0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955</del>

You are on testnet, my mistake.

I don't have access to your BUSD. But the factory contract does show a pool for it for you to swap through.

I did just test a couple of swaps using the addresses you have, for router and WBNB and they work.
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xda779fc16026d3429537b3f923b1714e8ed8f431cf86fb3c4fe710e2b3f549d7

I would try different routes and makes sure it's not a remix error by clearing cookies and pulling up the contract again, or trying through something like brownie.

Comment: i'm working on bsc testnet and here is tx hash and remix message

Comment: Ah testnet, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was that I should declare the path variable like this:

```
address[] memory path = new address[](3);
```